# Exporting evernote attachments, preserving creation date

Tags: python, evernote

My extended evaluation of Evernote is over, and it's time to get the attachments I've unwisely committed to its database back into my filesystem before removing it.

I have some basic facility with Python, and I've read the API, but I can't bridge the gap. My plan was to iterate over all the notes, check if it has an attachment, and write the attachment out to the filesystem under the note's title, and set the creation date to match. I I can't see if that is even possible in the API, let alone how to do it, and can't find any Python snippets capturing this kind of behaviour.

Since this might be a useful function, can anybody give me a skeleton to follow that I can work up into functioning code? Thank you very much.

(Exporting the attachments from within Evernote doesn't preserve creation date, of course).